# WCF – Get Caller identity from incoming user certificate

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, certificate

I have a WCF project that will process information submitted from a user. The service will be hosted such that it will require client certificates that we will issue to the users to be supplied when the service is called.

Within the service, I’d like to be able to retrieve something from the incoming certificate that can be used to identify the caller for business logic purposes.

I believe I have configured the web.config of the WCF service correctly and have configure the app.config of the calling client correctly. From within the WCF service, I don’t know how to get anything form the certificate supplied from the client caller. Included in the code below are some of the approaches I have tried.

I have tested it both from within IIS Express via Visual Studio and via regular IIS running on my dev box.

Here is the code of the WCF service (The code for IMessagingService can be supplied if needed but I dont think that is where the issue is.):

```
using MessagingService.Contracts.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace MessagingService.WCFService
{
    public class MessagingService : IMessagingService
    {
        public MessageResponse ProcessMessage(MessageRequest request)
        {
            /* I need an identity of the calling client to make some business decision */

            var ID = GetClientId();

            /* Message Processing to occur here, code not relevent */

            return new MessageResponse { Result = "Success" };
        }

        private string GetClientId()
        {
            /*Both of these are empty*/
            var id1 = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
            var id2 = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity;

            /*I found a tutorial about possibly extracting the cert in this manner but this does not work ether*/
            Type x509IdentityType = id2.GetType();
            /*This field does not exist and so certificateField ends up being null*/
            FieldInfo certificateField = x509IdentityType.GetField("certificate", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var cert = (X509Certificate2)certificateField.GetValue(id2);
            var id3 = cert.FriendlyName;


            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the web.config file for the service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding>
                    <security mode ="Message">
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                    <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true">
                        <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                        <clientCertificate>
                            <!--Development only setting. in PROD it will be ChainTrust-->
                            <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" />
                        </clientCertificate>
                    </serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Always" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is my client caller code:

```
using MessagingService.Contracts.Interfaces;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace MessagingService.WCFClient
{
    public class MessagingClient : ClientBase<IMessagingService>, IMessagingService
    {
        public MessagingClient()
        {

        }

        public MessageResponse ProcessMessage(MessageRequest request)
        {
            using (new OperationContextScope(this.InnerChannel))
            {
                return base.Channel.ProcessMessage(request);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is console app that makes the call:

```
using MessagingService.Contracts.Interfaces;
using System;

namespace MessagingService.WCFClient
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*This is here because I am dealing with self-sighed certs in my development environment - it wont be in PROD*/
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            try
            {
                IMessagingService sender = new MessagingClient();
                var result = sender.ProcessMessage(new MessageRequest
                { 
                    Message = "Test Message"

                });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine($"While Trying to call service\n{ex}");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the app.config of the console app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="basicHttpBinding_IMessaging" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                         openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                         maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                                  maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://localhost:44395/MessagingService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_IMessaging" 
                      behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertificateBehavior" 
                      contract="MessagingService.Contracts.Interfaces.IMessagingService">
            </endpoint>
        </client>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehavior">
                    <clientCredentials>
                        <clientCertificate findValue="[Thumbprint omitted but pulled from cert]" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
                        <serviceCertificate>
                            <!--Development only setting. in PROD it will be ChainTrust-->
                            <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"/>
                        </serviceCertificate>
                    </clientCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have any specific questions right now, I suggest you take a look at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-certificate-client).

Comment: @LanHuang I'll take a look at the documentation and report back if it helps me resolve my issue. Thanks!
My question/issue is that I can seem to access any information form the certificate provided by the caller within the WCF code and I am pretty sure that I have ether my server or client bindings (or both) incorrectly configured. I was hoping someone who has done this before can point out what I am doing wrong.